# Can any one explain me the below phrase?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

> A new ‘internship visa,’ approved by the Union Cabinet to help foreigners gain professional experience in India, does not include a “restricted category” to thwart applications from countries such as Pakistan and China.

This part in the sentence, *does not include a "restricted category"*, confuses me like it is not allowing restricted access or there is no restricted category. Can any one clarify me clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is what "to thwart applications from countries such as Pakistan and China" relates to.

1. If it's the *purpose* for not including a "restricted category", then your interpretation of *not allowing restricted access* holds.
2. If it is the *effect* of having a restricted category, then your alternate interpretation that *there is no restricted category* holds.

To me, the *purpose* variant (1) is the natural reading as an English sentence with the various parts read in isolation. However, this conflicts with the stated intent to "help foreigners ...".

On the other hand, having a "restricted category" might be diplomatic code for making allowances for people who are categorised in that way, validating the parsing of (1) above.

I conclude that this sentence is ambiguous without further context.

Comment: I will provide u the link of the context where it occurs http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/No-restrictions-on-foreign-interns/article16798324.ece?homepage=true

Comment: http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/No-restrictions-on-foreign-interns/article16798324.ece?homepage=true

Answer (score 0):

Check this following paragraph from the same article:

> Explaining the reason for not having any restricted list for this category of visa, the official said: “We welcome young people from across the world. There is going to be a surge in demand for such visas when foreign companies start operating here. We will decide each application on a case-by-case basis.

This paragraph clarifies that there is no restricted list in this category of visa.